# Return count of remaining values after calling remove duplicates method

Tags: vba, excel

I've got a couple of summary tables and I'm trying to automate the data coming from one to the other, the code is all currently working, but when I am re-assigning the "`Tier2`" named range I'm using `xlDown` and `xlRight` and it feels a bit sloppy to me.

I noticed that when you manually remove duplicates it gives you a `msgbox` with the count of remaining values.

Is there a way to have the remove duplicates method also return this property to a variable?

```
'copies the first two columns of the Tier3 table
Range([Tier3_anchor], WorksheetFunction.Index([Tier3], r, c)).Copy

'Pastes as values into the Tier2 table
Range("Tier2_Anchor").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

'removes duplicates from the Tier2 table
Range([Tier2_anchor], Cells([Tier2_anchor].Row + r - 1, [Tier2_anchor].Column + 1)).RemoveDuplicates Columns:=2, Header:=xlNo  

'This is a rough way to define the range of the Tier2 Table, there is a messagebox that returns remaining values after the remove duplicates, maybe able to capture that!   
Range("Tier2_anchor", Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight)).Name = "Tier2"
```

Ideally I'd be doing something like this:

```
Dim r As Integer
Dim c As Integer
r = UBound(A, 1)
c = UBound(A, 2)

'pastes the array into the workbook with the top left corner starting on the named range "Tier3_Anchor"
Range([Tier3_anchor], Cells(r + [Tier3_anchor].Row, c + [Tier3_anchor].Column)).Value = A
'renames the pasted data to Tier3
Range([Tier3_anchor], Cells([Tier3_anchor].Row + r, [Tier3_anchor].Column + c)).Name = "Tier3"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the `=COUNTA()` worksheet function?

```
'removes duplicates from the Tier2 table
Range([Tier2_anchor], Cells([Tier2_anchor].Row + r - 1, [Tier2_anchor].Column + 1)).RemoveDuplicates Columns:=2, Header:=xlNo  

'// Use CountA to get remaining values:
remainingValues = WorksheetFunction.CountA(Range([Tier2_anchor], Cells([Tier2_anchor].Row + r - 1, [Tier2_anchor].Column + 1)))

MsgBox remainingValues & " values remaining"
```

Comment: I do like that better than the xlDown approach, it's on my short-list :)